# Solana pay with laravel

Tags: solana-pay

How I can implement solana pay wallet with php or laravel?
Is there a document? Preferably without installing the plugin

Comment: We need more detail to help with this. Do you want to use transfer or transaction requests? Which plugin do you not want to install?

Comment: Thanks for reply, for transaction, I need deploy it's front in Nuxtjs and back in Laravel, For better performance, I need to avoid using additional and heavy plugins as possible in front side